# Export ssh key from Github servers

Tags: git, authentication, ssh, github, ssh-keys

I set up two ssh keys on my Github server, also I have an account on git kde servers, on my current machine there is one used by github, which works just fine and the other was synced by kde servers, which I deleted from my machine and I am searching for a way to export it from github to re-sync it with kde servers. I hope that I am clear.

EDIT: I deleted the key on kde servers, and I need to export the one on Github to kde servers

Comment: Did you delete a git repository, or an ssh key? Clarify the subjects in your question, please!

Comment: You want to download your public key from Github? Would this question be better directed to [Github's support?](https://github.com/contact)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understood the question correctly - you lost your public key.

If you still have your private key, you can regenerate your public key easily enough

```
 ssh-keygen -y [-f input_keyfile]
 -y      This option will read a private OpenSSH format file and print an
         OpenSSH public key to stdout.
```

For example:

```
$ ssh-keygen -y -f myprivatekey > myregeneratedpublickey.pub
```

If you've lost your private key, you're stuck. You'll have to generate a new keypair.

Comment: Thanks man, that is what I am asking for, unfortunately I lost my private key so I will make a new key pair.